# Floating a DIV within another DIV

Tags: html, css

For my webpages I have a container DIV, within that a menu DIV and a content DIV. I am arranging several 'settings' DIVs within the content DIV and I wan them to float left within the content DIV but lower ones end up under the menu DIV.

Check this jsfiddle to see clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/4KUTy/5/

The `settings` `divs` have the properties of `float:right;` but that leaves the last one in the wrong position and if I `float:left;`, then it goes under the menu.

Please help.

jsfiddle html code here:

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>menu option 1</li>
            <li>menu option 2</li>
            <li>menu option 3</li>
            <li>menu option A</li>
            <li>menu option B</li>
            <li>menu option C</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="settings_div">Project Settings<br/>
    <ul style="display:inline-block">
        <li>language</li>
        <li>currency</li>
        <li>mark up</li>
    </ul>
</div>     
<div class="settings_div">Your Company Settings<br/>
    <ul style="display:inline-block">
        <li>company details</li>
        <li>bank details</li>
        <li>contact details</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="settings_div">Output Settings   <br/>
    <ul style="display:inline-block">
        <li>company logo</li>
        <li>date format</li>
        <li>fonts etc</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="settings_div">Graphical Settings<br/>
    <ul style="display:inline-block">
        <li>colors</li>
        <li>text size</li>
        <li>more</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="settings_div">I WANT THIS ONE ON THE LEFT!<br/>
    <ul style="display:inline-block">
        <li>But NOT under the menu</li>
        <li>float:left puts it under the menu</li>
        <li>should be under graphical settings</li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </div>            
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle css here:

```
.settings_div {
    text-align:left;
    display:inline;
    width:300px;
    height:80px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin:20px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-color:#33CCCC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thick;
    float:right;
}

#content {
    width:600;
    min-height:620px;
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline;
}

.menu { 
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#33CCCC;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width:auto;
}

#container {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:950px;
    min-height:620px;
    border-radius:0px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-10;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container of the floated divs should have:

```
overflow: hidden; /* Makes the container actually "contain" the floated divs */
display: block;
```

The floated divs should be

```
float:left
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4KUTy/5/

I found a nice post that attempts to explain why overflow:hidden works the way it does: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

In case the link dies: Setting overflow to anything other than visible will cause it to establish a new block formatting context (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting).

Comment: Yours was the simplest answer and it worked. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: It sure workds, but I cannot understand what the overflow and the display:block has to do with it. Any link, please?

Comment: @opensas Added a couple of links to help you

Answer (score 2):

Two things are wrong here:

- The wrapper div.content is set to display: inline.
- The wrapper div.content does not scale correctly since all child elements are out of the flow.

In order to make the setting divs behave correctly use:

```
 .content { display: block; overflow: hidden; }
```

and then float left all setting div's.

See updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4KUTy/7/

Comment: +1 Thanks for posting - your solution is exactly what I needed. @cermunnos got there first though... =)

Comment: I checked, I beat him with a few seconds. But it doesn't matter, glad you got it working. xD

Answer (score 0):

Just add a placeholder div before the last div

```
<div class="settins_div placeholder">placeholder</div>
```

and add css-rule

```
.placeholder{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

have a jsfiddle to check: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DK64V/1/)

Comment: Very close but no cigar. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Make all `settings_div` `float:left;`, but use another container that floats right and is wide enough:

```
<div id="setting-container" style="float:right;width:800px;">
    <div class="settings_div">Your Company Settings<br/>
        <ul style="display:inline-block">
            <li>company details</li>
            <li>bank details</li>
            <li>contact details</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="settings_div">Output Settings   <br/>
        <ul style="display:inline-block">
            <li>company logo</li>
            <li>date format</li>
            <li>fonts etc</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="settings_div">Graphical Settings<br/>
        <ul style="display:inline-block">
            <li>colors</li>
            <li>text size</li>
            <li>more</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="settings_div">I WANT THIS ONE ON THE LEFT!<br/>
        <ul style="display:inline-block">
            <li>But NOT under the menu</li>
            <li>float:left puts it under the menu</li>
            <li>should be under graphical settings</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4JhS/11/)

Comment: +1 Thanks for replying - works fine but @cermunnos answer was more concise (no need to add another div) so chose that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are only small changes to your css rules:

You should add a fixed width to your menu.

```
.menu { 
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#33CCCC;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width:150px;
}
```

And your container needs to be "moved" by that value + margin to the right. So add a `margin-left` to it:

```
#content {
    width:600;
    min-height:620px;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-left: 160px;
}
```

Set your `#container` to `overflow: hidden`.

And now every settings div should be floated left.

An updated version of your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4KUTy/8/

Comment: Thanks for posting - your solution seems to work fine but I went for a simpler answer without involving margins. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my result http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/4KUTy/10/

**Major Changes**

- I changed a lot of the `float` properties to `display:inline-block`. The reason for this is so that all of the elements position themselves correctly.
- I took off the width for `container`, so now it should be slightly more responsive
- I removed the `settings_div` class and changed the CSS to `#content div` to save code
- Added `display:inline-block` to the `ul` in the CSS and took it off of the inline styles
- A rather large problem was you had a property of the content set as `width:600`, when it needed to be `width:600px;`. I ended up removing this style.
- Because you had the `#container` set to a positioning of `relative`, then I changed `margin-top:-10;` to `top:-10px;`

**Small Changes**

- Condensed a lot of properties such as `margin` and `border`
- Removed the `width`, `overflow`, and `min-height` from container because they served no purpose

**Update** - http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/4KUTy/12/

- Added `border-box` to every element so that it will display the exact width that you specify
- Added a fluid width to `container` so that it will display inline with the menu when needed, but then will drop down when it is too full

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. The Divs aren't quite where I wanted them though. =)

Comment: Dude the divs were not in the correct place - they float under the menu when the screen width is reduced, which I did not want. However, I probably did not make that 100% clear so +1 for all your efforts. =)